# Hook to provide a value for every Hash lookup in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

Is it possible to provide a hook in Perl to make sure no Hash key lookup fails ?

Example :

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
my %hash_example = ( "a"=>"apple", "b"=>"ball" ); 
print $hash_example{"a"};  # Goes Fine. 
print $hash_example{"c"};  # Throws Warning  ( "Use of uninitialized value " ).
```

[Codepad link](http://codepad.org/S2IPBaNf)

Whenever a hash lookup happens, some subroutine could get called which can provide a default value.

I mean, any hash lookup should call a sub ( say "`get_hash_value (hash_ref, key)` " ) and pass the hash and key to it. A sample of such a sub is shown below :

```
sub get_hash_value { 
    my $hash_ref = shift; 
    my $key      = shift; 
    if ( exists $hash_ref->{$key} ) { # For Normal Lookup. 
        return $hash_ref->{$key}; 
    } 
    else { 
        # This is the interesting place where we could provide our own values. 
        return "custom_value_based_on_certain_conditions";  # Some value 
    } 
}
```

Another consequence would be the ability to alter the value returned against a key.  We would be able to return a different value than what actually is stored against that key ( in that hash ).

There might not be a valid use case for this but am intrigued and would like to learn if such things are supported in Perl.

Comment: `print $hash_example{"c"} if defined $hash_example{"c"};` or `print $hash_example{"c"} // ""` depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: @Сухой27 Thanks but I know that. What I want to do is to have my own sub called in the process of hash lookup so that I could alter the returned value. I have updated the question with more data.

Comment: https://eval.in/319851 (it also alters original hash by adding missing key)

Comment: This is called object oriented perl, and yes, there are a LOT of use cases for it :)

Answer (score 3):

As said by Сухой27 in comment, this works fine:

```
my %hash_example = ( "a"=>"apple", "b"=>"ball" ); 
print $hash_example{"a"};  
print $hash_example{"c"} // "custom_value_based_on_certain_conditions";
```

Doc on [logical defined or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or)

Comment: I think it would be worth noting that anything that obfuscates the conditional assignment is a place where future programmers will be sad. Sometimes it's good to be explicit about what's going on!

Comment: @Сухой27 Thanks and +1. Your approach solves the initial question which I had but i later expanded my question to include more scope which Sobrique has explained.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that trying to alter how a hash lookup "works" is a really terrible idea, as a good way to create code that's hard to maintain.

However instead I would suggest you look at creating an *object* instead of a hash. They are basically the same thing, but an object includes code, and there is an *expectation* that the code within the object is 'doing it's own thing'.

So at a basic level:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package Hash_Ob;

sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless( $self, $class );
    return $self;
}

sub get_value {
    my ( $self, $valuename ) = @_;
    if ( $self->{$valuename} ) {
        return $self->{$valuename};
    }
    else {
        #generate your own value here!
        $self->{$valuename} = 42;
        return $self->{$valuename};
    }
}

1;
```

Which you'd then 'call' using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Hash_Ob;

my $magic_hash = Hash_Ob -> new();

print $magic_hash -> get_value('new_value');
```

This avoids the problem of altering how a 'well known' mechanism actually works, and so future maintenance programmers will not curse your name.

Comment: Thanks. I believe using an object, instead of hash directly, would provide me the required flexibility. I would go back and study OO Perl and come back to mark this answer as accepted. Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: I've given you a very basic OO example. It goes a lot deeper, depending on exactly what you want to do. You may find it worth your time to look at `Moose` which is related to perl OO - but it's a bit more intensive initially.

Answer (score 2):

Then maybe you want to use a tied hash. Tying is a mechanism to change the behavior of a builtin data type. See [`perltie`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perltie) for the gory details.

```
{
    package HashWithDefault;
    use Tie::StdHash;
    our @ISA = qw(Tie::StdHash);    # inherit STORE, FIRST, NEXT, etc.
    sub TIEHASH {
        my ($pkg,$default_val) = @_;
        return bless { __default_val__ => $default_val}, $pkg;
    }
    sub FETCH {
        my ($self,$key) = @_;
        exists $self->{$key} ? $self->{$key} : $self->{__default_val__};
    }
    sub CLEAR {  # don't clear the default val
        my $self = shift;
        %$self = ( __default_val__ => $self->{__default_val__} );
    }
}

tie my %hash, 'HashWithDefault', "42";
%hash = (foo => 123, bar => 456);
print $hash{foo};   # 123
print $hash{quux};  # 42
```